# Using Akka Route TestKit with Kotlin Spek

Tags: kotlin, akka, akka-http

I am trying to test my AkkaHTTP routes (written in Kotlin) using akka-http-testkit. The tests in our project use Spek and I would like to keep it this way.
The [Route TestKit tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html) gives a Java example:

```
public class TestkitExampleTest extends JUnitRouteTest {
    TestRoute appRoute = testRoute(new MyAppService().createRoute())

    @Test
    public void testCalculatorAdd() {
        // test happy path
        appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=4.2&y=2.3"))
            .assertStatusCode(200)
            .assertEntity("x + y = 6.5")

        // test responses to potential errors
        appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=3.2"))
            .assertStatusCode(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND) // 404
            .assertEntity("Request is missing required query parameter 'y'")

        // test responses to potential errors
        appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=3.2&y=three"))
            .assertStatusCode(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
            .assertEntity("The query parameter 'y' was malformed:\n" +
                "'three' is not a valid 64-bit floating point value")
    }
}
```

The setup uses the `testRoute` function, which means the test class must extend `JUnitRouteTest`.

Attempting to translate to a Kotlin Spek test I got this:

```
class TestKitExampleTest : JUnitRouteTest(), Spek({

  describe("My routes") {
    val appRoute = testRoute(MyAppService().createRoute())

    it("calculator add") {
      // test happy path
      appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=4.2&y=2.3"))
        .assertStatusCode(200)
        .assertEntity("x + y = 6.5")
      //...rest omitted
    }
  }
})
```

which does not compile as the class is attempting to inherit two classes. I converted it to the following instead:

```
class TestKitExampleTest : Spek({

  describe("My routes") {
    val appRoute = testRoute(MyAppService().createRoute())

    it("calculator add") {
      // test happy path
      appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=4.2&y=2.3"))
        .assertStatusCode(200)
        .assertEntity("x + y = 6.5")
      //...rest omitted
    }
  }
}) {
  companion object : JUnitRouteTest()
}
```

which encouters the runtime error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown factory null
    at akka.http.impl.util.package$.actorSystem(package.scala:34)`.

Is there a way to use Akka's route testkit with Spek? Or is there another way to test these routes?

Comment: Question was answered on spek's issue tracker: https://github.com/spekframework/spek/issues/453.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @raniejade mentioned above, answered on Github. `JUnitRouteTest` bootstraps Akka with a rule, but Spek's `LifeCycleListener` can do the same thing.

Adding the code:

```
class SpekRouteBootstrapper: LifecycleListener, JUnitRouteTest() {
  override fun beforeExecuteTest(test: TestScope) {
    systemResource().before()
  }

  override fun afterExecuteTest(test: TestScope) {
    systemResource().after()
  }
}
```

allowed me to do this on the test class:

```
class TestKitExampleTest: Spek({
  val bootstrapper = SpekRouteBootstrapper()
  registerListener(bootstrapper)

  describe("My routes") {
    val appRoute by memoized {
      bootstrapper.testRoute(MyAppService().createRoute())
    }

    it("calculator add") {
      // test happy path
      appRoute.run(HttpRequest.GET("/calculator/add?x=4.2&y=2.3"))
        .assertStatusCode(200)
        .assertEntity("x + y = 6.5")
    }
  }
})
```